# Losing custom segments in batch file transformation

Tags: mirth

I'm working with a file that is batched messages from the Meditech Expanse system. This file currently goes to the State where I'm located and they both want it done as a batch file but also require that Meditech includes these two custom segments at the top of the file.

FHS|^~&|LAB|ANHMT|||202010202359||||14041745|
BHS|^~&|LAB|ANHMT|||202010202359||||14041745|

I'm making a minor transformation to the PID segment in the file which I've got worked out but the issue is when I "re-create" the file with PID transformations in place I'm losing the aforementioned segments.

I'm guessing this is due to Split Batch By setting within the Set Data Types area on the Summary tab of the channel but maybe that's wrong I'm not sure?? Either way that's what I'm trying to figure out is HOW to get those two segments in the "final"product file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some screenshots in your question? Please be sure that no PHI is included.